# Searching for a free USB Autorun creator for Windows

Tags: usb, autorun, inf

Since I used Samlogic's USB Autorun creator but it has a limit for 30days. So I can't able to use it anymore.

And I tried removing totally from the system and tried again reinstalling looking to use it again, but it still shows product expired. So here now, I am looking for any cracked versions or an alternative to the Samlogic's USB Autorun creator.

Comment: You should use intellectual property beyond what's granted by the owner, not even try to. You should not involve others.